# How to hide a table row that has no unique id

Tags: jquery

How to hide a table row  that has no unique id,  but row just contains TD with a specific text,
note that I cannot adjust the classnames or add ID's there either. Its nested TR.

eg.

```
<tbody><tr>
<table id="baskettable"><tbody>
<tr class="SeparateRow ">
           <td class="SeparateColumn" colspan="2"> DO not hide this row</td>
           <td class="SeparateColumn"></td>
           <td class="SeparateColumn"></td>
          <td class="Money">100,39 </td>
          <td></td>   </tr>

<tr class="SeparateRow ">
           <td class="SeparateColumn" colspan="2"> yes hide this row</td>
           <td class="SeparateColumn"></td>
           <td class="SeparateColumn"></td>
          <td class="Money">100,39 </td>
          <td></td>   </tr>
```

Comment: I don't see duplicate ID in your example, but by definition, having two elements with the same ID means that you have a problem somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("tr.SeparateRow:contains('something to find')").hide();
```

working example --> http://jsfiddle.net/ukJxH/1/

Comment: thanks, but my page has nested TRs  and now the whole outer TR is hidden.  any ideas how to limit what to hide?

Comment: @Tom - How about you update the question with all the pertinent information instead of partial info.